# Calculate convolution $x_n * y_n$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Having these two sequences:

$x_n = u_n u_{-n}$

$y_n = (n+1) u_n u_{3-n}$

Then the convolution of $ x_n * y_n $ equals...

The options are:

A. $x_n $

B. $y_n $

C. $(n+1) u_{n-4} u_{7-n}$

D.  $(n-3) u_{n-4} u_{7-n}$

Note: $u_n = 1$ if  $n \geq 0$ and $u_n = 0$ if  $n < 0$

Since $x_n$ seems to be always 0, then I'd say option would be A but apparently the correct option is B??

Update: $x_n$ is always 0 except when n = 0.

Ok so by definition Convolution would be something like:

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_t * y_{n-t} dn $

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_n y_{n-t} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_n u_{-n} (n-t+1) u_{n-t} u_{3-(n-t)} dt $

But since $x_t$ is only 1 when n = 0.
Then I would only evaluate

$\int_{0}^0 (n-t+1) dt = 0 $

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: $x_n$ is not always $0$ look at it again

Comment: @Legorhin true, except when n = 0. Thanks.

Comment: Now that you have realized that the answer should be easy to get. If not you should go reread whatever textbook chapter this is related to because this is one of the most basic examples used to teach discrete convolution.

Comment: @Legorhin Ok I get that the answer would be $y_n$ but wouldn't that be only for n = 0?

Comment: these are signals so you care about all values of $n$ at the same time

Comment: @Legorhin I just updated my question. I have barely any knowledge about these type of problems, I watched several videos but they all have some integral limits which are different than for this case. Could you help me? Or at least provide me some useful links or examples which could be useful.

Comment: Wouldn't the convolution of sequences be a sum of the form $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x_k y_{n-k}$, not an integral? Or maybe that's what you mean by $dn$ (counting measure)?

Comment: @Bungo Ok, now that would make some sense, thank you

Comment: Now how do I know if I have to integrate or make a sum? (when calculating a convolution)

Comment: Convolution of sequences $\implies$ sum. Convolution of functions of a real variable $\implies$ integral.

Comment: Thank you very much to you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolution of sequences is computed using a sum, not an integral. Specifically, if $x_n$ and $y_n$ are sequences, then their convolution is
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x_k y_{n-k}$$
In your case, $x_k = u_k u_{-k}$, which as you pointed out, is zero for $k \neq 0$, and $x_0 = u_0^2 = 1$. In other words,
$$x_n = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if $n = 0$ } \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$
which is often written as $x_n = \delta_n$.

This means that only the $k=0$ term in the convolution sum is nonzero:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x_k y_{n-k} = x_0 y_{n-0} = y_n$$
So (b) is the correct answer. Note that this choice of $x_n$ satisfies $x_n * y_n = y_n$ for any sequence $y_n$. We say that $x_n = \delta_n$ is an identity with respect to the convolution operation.